# jQuery Mobile - Back button is not shown

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/dGJEH/

Why is the back button not shown?

My page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="details" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Tillbaka">
```

It has been there, but somehow it just disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Since JQM version 1.0, back button is off by default.

You have to explicitly specify that you want to display it:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
});
```

[Automatic toolbar back button: Now off by default](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/06/20/jquery-mobile-beta-1-released/#backbtn)

Though, it's kind of weird that you already had it without that trick.

Comment: For more recent versions of JQueryMobile you will need to use: $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.addBackBtn (a very small difference)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what Dessus mentioned helped! (a very small but significant difference)

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
    $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.backBtnText = "Lets go back!"
});
```

Thanks Dessus!